# Symfony 2 kernel service class not defined?

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to use SF2's framework bundle as the base of my framework and ran into this issue:

The container cannot get "kernel" service because the class is empty. I looked into the services.xml file of the bundle and found this line

```
<service id="kernel" synthetic="true" />
```

The class is not defined, I assume it is defined some where else that I'm not aware of. I wonder if I missed anything in the settings (I installed the bundle manually via git, not through composer right now)

Any pointer would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically kernel service is synthetic... it mean that service is not constructed by container but is injected to it so can used later... in this specific case Kernel is passed to container by itself after container init when [kernel is booted](https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/blob/master/Kernel.php#L592).